# Unexpected white background on top of carousel images in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css

I don't understand why an unexpected white background appears on top of the bootstrap 4 carousel  when I apply a black background color. How can I correct this unexpected issue? You can find the example of this issue here https://codepen.io/edquijano/pen/MQxogR  Thanks for your input.

```
   <div class="carousel">
    <div class="bg-dark">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/hero.jpg" alt="First slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/hero.jpg" alt="Second slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/hero.jpg" alt="Third slide">
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you share the screenshot of the white background you are talking about? I'm not sure which area you are pointing to.

Comment: Yes there is a codepen. Here it's https://codepen.io/edquijano/pen/MQxogR

Comment: Yes, in the codepen, are you talking about the white background in the navbar? Cuz, I don't see anything wrong with the carousel.

Comment: The white background is on top of the carousel images. The navbar has a white bg.

Comment: I checked from my laptop and, the white bg is there. You can increase the opacity and you'll see the washout img.

Comment: Got what you meant now.

Answer (score 0):

The carousel is enclosed in an `overlay` div, which comes with an opacity of 0.6. This makes the images look like they have a whitish cast over them.
You can either choose to remove the `overlay` div or explicity set `opacity:1` on the images. 
Here is the output with the `overlay` div removed: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XZGevv